# Does annoations work for Service Builder classes in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I tried to add an annotation to a service implementation class like this:

```
@Component
public class MyServiceImpl extends MyServiceBaseImpl {
    @ReadThroughSingleCache
    public String hello(String name){
        ......
    }
}
```

This annotation doesn't work like this. Does Liferay service builder support this? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this annotation?

Comment: Liferay is already caching data at the persistence layer when you use ServiceBuilder.

Comment: i dont think annotation scan is active inside service builder generated class...